# Multiple SimpleMembershipProviders

Tags: c#, .net, simplemembership

I have multiple customer websites on one server that all have their own databases with their own SimpleMembershipProvider. I also have a Windows Service (using Quartz.NET scheduler) that does various things for all customers.

I want to be able to access all the membership databases for all the clients from the service (for example to import users) but SimpleMembershipProvider is a static class and only allows you to initialise once. I can't seem to dispose it or anything. Is there any way round this?

I've looked at trying to create a SimpleMembershipProvider instance and using the Initalize() method but to no avail.

I tried to use different SqlMembershipProviders in the app.config and directly use those providers methods but that requires all the SqlMembershipProvider stored procedures.

I could access the databases directly of course but that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: just go for the database directly. don't over complicate it for your self